# Search Users base on meta_value & meta_key

Tags: users, user-meta

How can i use multiple meta_key and meta_value to search users?

For example, i want to search & find user name is "David" & location in "London".

I'm using this query, But nothings in result!

```
$query = "SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE (meta_value LIKE '%%david%%') AND (meta_key = 'first_name') AND (meta_value LIKE '%%london%%') AND (meta_key = 'location')";

$rows = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is wrong that's way noting is returned because there is no row in the database that holds more then one meta_key.
What you can do instead is create a Sub Query to get all user id's of users who live in London as a Sub Query and the use that to filter users id's of users who are named David, something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta
    WHERE (meta_value LIKE '%%david%%') 
    AND (meta_key = 'first_name') 
    AND user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM $wpdb->usermeta WHERE (meta_value LIKE '%%london%%') AND (meta_key = 'location'))";

$rows = $wpdb->get_results($query)
```